# Make the page scrollable in Windows 8 app

Tags: html, css, windows-8, winjs

I can't find anything similar to a SIMPLE scrollable body for Windows 8 app in Javascript.

I don't want to use listView. I think it's only when you have boxes of elements right ?

I have this simple app (converting timestamp)
[image: windows 8 simulator]

You can see that there are other input fields and other elements at the bottom of the tablet but I cannot scroll to see them !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, actually this was quite a stupid question.
I found it reading some windows 8 samples.
I just needed to add on the body the css

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: I was stuck at the same stupid place. thanks for sharing your finding